# How to optimize logout in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, logout

I have logout functionality where for a specific user, we need to make a backend API call and then proceed the response from API call is not taking much time but the logout process is taking up to 6-7seconds, I am looking ways to optimize this but couldn't find any. Following is my code,

```
if(localStorage['currentUser']=='xyz'){
          this.http.post('url', email).subscribe(res => {
            localStorage.clear();
            this.router.navigate(['login']).then(() => {
              this.store.dispatch(new Logout());
            })
          })
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create new `Logout()`, just need to use BehaviorSubject and next to the null value in the function `logout()`.

```
authenticate$: Subject<User | ErrorMessages> = new BehaviorSubject<
        User | ErrorMessages
    >(null);
...
logout(): void {
    this.authenticate$.next(null);
    this.localStorageService.clearAllCache();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```